# create/alter procedure with if object_id is not null then drop?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I want that the procedure first checks, if the temp table already exists. If it does then drop the table and move on to select into the table. But I got this error:

```
'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch.
```

My code looks like this:

```
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetData]
    @Param_Id int
AS
BEGIN

If OBJECT_ID('temp_table') is not null
drop table temp_table

select data_info into temp_table
from data_info_table1

END
```

But I keep on getting the same error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can't see why that code would cause that error. Is that all the code you have in the query window?

Comment: basically, yes.. I have three select into commands and thats it.. I just need to make sure that the tables dont already exist..

Comment: Well the error message is complaining that "CREATE/ALTER **PROCEDURE**" must be the first statement in the query batch. Not sure why you think that has anything to do with the code inside the stored procedure that you have posted.

Comment: [check here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10900598/1425057)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the Procedure to ansi Nulls? Try setting your Set Ansi Null On inside of the procedure.

Also, if you are executing this manually, you can change the options first by selecting only that code and running it, then selecting only the stored procedure and running it separately.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same error Message when the script is like below. That means `GO` statement is missing.

```
if Exists(select object_id from sys.objects where name = 'GetData' and type = 'p')
Begin
    Drop Proc GetData
End
GO --Missing part
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetData]
@Param_Id int
AS
BEGIN
    If OBJECT_ID('temp_table') is not null
       drop table temp_table

    select data_info into temp_table from data_info_table1
END
```

Answer (score 0):

The GO command indicates the end of a batch of T-SQL statements. Any statements after the GO command indicates the beginning of a new batch of queries or T-SQL statements. So, I suggest you remove the GO commands at the beginning and retain the one before the CREATE statement hence that now becomes the first statement in the succeeding query batch.

The statement will look like below

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetData] @Param_Id int
AS
BEGIN

If OBJECT_ID('temp_table') IS NOT NULL DROP table temp_table

SELECT data_info INTO temp_table FROM data_info_table1

END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to create possibility that 2 different users loose their data because you are using permanent structure in database, right? That what will happen if you create static table. Then it is actually pretty simple. If You working with the session temp tables (name would look like #temp_table) you need to look for those things in tempdb database like that:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp_table') IS NOT NULL
```

Do this is just a precautionary measures because tables which names started with # get deleted upon completion of the query and those are query specific which means it will not interfere with parallel connection by other user or request. And your entire script should look like that:

```
GO
If OBJECT_ID('GetData') is not null
      drop PROCEDURE GetData
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetData]
    @Param_Id int
AS
BEGIN

   If OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp_table') is not null
        drop table #temp_table

   select data_info into #temp_table
   from data_info_table1

    -- do what ever you need to do here with you data and spit it out to user.
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting GO after the DROP TABLE. I find that 
IF OBJECT_ID(**) IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ** 
doesn't always work by itself, but it appears to be reliable with GO after it:
IF OBJECT_ID(**) IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ** 
GO

Answer (score 0):

There is a compiler error.
If you really want to create this procedure and if the table temp_table is the really the tamp table you can try drop it before creating the procedure.
like this:

```
If OBJECT_ID('temp_table') is not null
drop table temp_table
go

create PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetData]
    @Param_Id int
AS
BEGIN

If OBJECT_ID('temp_table') is not null
drop table temp_table

select data_info into temp_table
from data_info_table1

END
```

or really use a temporary table like #table, ##table or @table

Answer (score -1):

What if you change your stored procedure with this?:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetData]
    @Param_Id int
AS
BEGIN

If EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name = 'temp_table')
BEGIN
    drop table temp_table
END

DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(1000)
SET @SQL = '
select data_info into temp_table
from data_info_table1'

EXEC(@SQL)

END
```

Comment: tried it.. but getting: There is already an object named 'temp_table' in the database.

Comment: @user1129988 - Basically, the sp doesn't realize that you are verifying the existence of the table an dropping it if it already exists before the `INTO`, so it tells you that is a duplicate. Try wrapping it on a dynamic query, it should work fine. I updated my answer.

Comment: is this an efficient method.. because I dont have just one select 'into'  I have three

Comment: @user1129988 - Is just as efficient as creating your table with an `INTO`. I'm not talking about putting your whole sp on a dynamic query, just your `INTO` statements.

Comment: @user1129988 - No, since the engine won't recognize that the table was dropped, just as you have now. So, either you execute the `INTO` dynamically, or instead of dropping and creating your table over and over, you do a `DELETE` and and `INSERT INTO`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12170/discussion-between-lamak-and-user1129988)

Comment: hey.. you still around for a chat?